# Java Gui won't display panels and components

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

im trying to make a program to add an admin to a ms access database

I researched many times, figured out all the components need to be in a panel, and only the same type of J stuff can be in a panel, so i made many panels and combined them in a big panel

```
        //frame details
        final int FRAME_WIDTH = 1000; 
        final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 1000; 
        JFrame aFrame = new JFrame("Add admin"); 
        aFrame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT); 
        aFrame.setVisible(true); 
        aFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

        //panel declaration
        JPanel BigPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel adminnameenter = new JPanel();
        JPanel typeadminname = new JPanel();
        JPanel adminlastnameenter = new JPanel();
        JPanel typeadminlastname = new JPanel();
        JPanel buttonaddadmin = new JPanel();

        //labels, textfields, and buttons
        JLabel newAdminName = new JLabel("Enter admin name");
        JTextField adminName = new JTextField(7);
        JLabel newadminlastname = new JLabel("Enter admin last name");
        JTextField adminlastname = new JTextField(7);
        JButton addadmin = new JButton("Add Admin");

        //add things to panel
        adminnameenter.add(newAdminName);
        typeadminname.add(adminName);
        adminlastnameenter.add(newadminlastname);
        typeadminlastname.add(adminlastname);
        buttonaddadmin.add(addadmin); 

        //add things to big jPanel
        BigPanel.add(adminnameenter);
        BigPanel.add(typeadminname);
        BigPanel.add(adminlastnameenter);
        BigPanel.add(typeadminlastname);
        BigPanel.add(buttonaddadmin);

        //add things to frame
        aFrame.add(BigPanel);
```

the only thing that popped up was a frame that said add admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to the end of your function:

```
aFrame.setVisible(false);
aFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Or alternatively put

```
aFrame.setVisible(true);
```

at the end of your function instead of the beginning.

And all the components will appear. This is because whenever you change anything to your JFrame, it will only change on the user side once it is told to resize or refresh the frame. Also you don't need to put every single component in it's own JPanel, you can simply insert them directly in your BigPanel (small nitpick, but the b in bigPanel, shouldn't be capitalized, seeing as variables start with non-capitalized letters).

Also look into LayoutManagers, they will probably be useful for your application.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: Thanks, just one question, could:
BigPanel.add(newAdminName);
  BigPanel.add(adminName);
  BigPanel.add(newadminlastname);
  BigPanel.add(adminlastname);
  BigPanel.add(addadmin);
be turned into BigPanel.add(addadmin, adminlastname, etc);

Comment: No, the closest you can get to that kind of behaviour would be to create an array with all those elements and loop through it.